# .htaccess RewriteRule url to new

Tags: .htaccess

Bonjour,

I try to redirect urls of a website
Example :

www.exemple.net/?p=2
to
www.exemple.net/index-2.html

www.exemple.net/?p=35 
to 
www.exemple.net/index-35.html
etc...

So i add this lines to my .htacess :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?)p=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /index-%1.html  [L,R=301]
```

But i'm redirected to http://www.exemple.net/index-2.html?p=2

My .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exemple.net$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.exemple.net/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?)p=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /index-%1.html  [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a question mark at the end of the destination to discard the query string:

```
RewriteRule .*  /index-%1.html?  [L,R=301]
```

Alternatively, use the `QSD` flag:

```
RewriteRule .*  /index-%1.html  [QSD,L,R=301]
```

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?)p=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /index-%1.html? [L,R=301]

Comment: It works thanks with :

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?)p=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /index-%1.html? [L,R=301]
But i have another problem, If i have urls like:

www.exemple.net/transfert.php?p=2

It sends me too: index-2.html

In reality, i have 3 kinds of urls that i want to redirect :

www.exemple.net/?p=2 To www.exemple.net/index-2.html

www.exemple.net/transfer?p=2 To www.exemple.net/transfer-2.html

www.exemple.net/blog?p=2 To www.exemple.net/blog-2.html

How can i do for the others urls, i think now my method is not the good ?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
#Redirecting /?p=2
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/\?p=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index-%1.html? [NE,NC,R,L]

 #Redirecting /transfer?p=2
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/transfer\?p=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /transfer-%1.html? [NE,NC,R,L]

 #Redirecting /blog?p=2
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/blog\?p=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog-%1.html? [NE,NC,R,L]
```

Comment: can you tell me the signification of  [^&\s]+  ?

Comment: ([^&\s]+) matches (the value of query string) any characters excluding "&" and spaces.